# How to instantiated this ListNode struct in C++?

Tags: c++

I am confused about the struct in Leetcode (Algorithm #2).

```
struct ListNode {
    int val;
    ListNode *next;
    ListNode() : val(0), next(nullptr) {}
    ListNode(int x) : val(x), next(nullptr) {}
    ListNode(int x, ListNode *next) : val(x), next(next) {}
  };
```

The first problem is I dont know how to instantiated an object by this struct，for example, I tried this to create a list 2 -> 4 -> 3:

```
int main(){
 ListNode p1_1 = ListNode(2);
 ListNode p1_2 = ListNode(4, &p1_1);
 ListNode p1_3 = ListNode(3, &p1_2);
//ListNode_output(&p1_1);
 return 0;
}
```

However, when I put it to my output function:

```
void ListNode_output(ListNode * list_input)
{
    while(list_input){
        cout << list_input->val << ' ';
        list_input->next;
    } 
    cout << endl;
}
```

it only output firstNode '2' endless, what is the main problem in my code. Besides, where can I check the manuscript of this struct, I mean why check node's value use '`ListNode->val`', rather '`ListNode.val`'?

Now, I follow some code that shows,

```
ListNode *l1_1 = new ListNode;
l1_1 -> val = 2;
l1_1 -> next = nullptr;
   
ListNode *l1_2 = new ListNode;
l1_2 -> val = 4;
l1_2 -> next = nullptr;

ListNode *l1_3 = new ListNode;
l1_3 -> val = 3;
l1_3 -> next = nullptr;

l1_1 -> next = l1_2;
l1_2 -> next = l1_3;

ListNode_output(l1_1);
```

and now, it can correctly show by `ListNode_output` function, but I am not sure if there is some more simple may can create list...

Comment: Regarding `ListNode->val` versus `ListNode.val`, it seems you might need to go back to your text-books and refresh the chapters on pointers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The statement

```
list_input->next;
```

fetches the value of `list_input->next` and then does nothing with it.

You probably want:

```
list_input = list_input->next;
```

That will make `list_input` point to the next element in the list.

---

Also, how you create the list, the call `ListNode_output(&p1_1)` should be `ListNode_output(&p1_3)` to print the whole list (`&p1_1` will point to the last node in the list).

To help visualize things like lists, use pencil and paper. When you create a node, draw a small box. When you create a pointer or a link from one node to another, draw an arrow. When you modify a pointer or a link then erase and redraw the arrow. If you do that then you will see why `ListNode_output(&p1_1)` is wrong.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply at first, I follow your instruction and add some new part after my question, could you please have a look if you have time?